# No touch gestures were set, but tabBar only responds to long press. Why?

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbar

I have a view which has a tabBar at the top, and below it is a tableView. The tableView has touch gestures which are constrained to it (tap, double tap, and pan gesture). However, the tabBar has no touch gestures installed but only responds to a long press touch.

Some useful information:
- tabBar delegate was set to self

only tabBar code:

```
func tabBar(_ tabBar: UITabBar, didSelect item: UITabBarItem) {
    if item.tag == 101 { //tag number of first tab bar item
        print("tableView")
    }
    if item.tag == 102 { //tag number of second tab bar item
        print("collectionView") //going to add collection view eventually
    }
}
```

any help will be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Does the tableView extend up underneath the tabbar? By the way, tab bars generally go at the bottom of the view, do you mean a navigationController?

Comment: @Magnas I have a search bar hidden in the table view header that extends out as I swipe down on the table view, so I guess that goes underneath the tab bar? Generally, yeah, tab bars do go at the bottom but I added one near the top of my screen similar to how instagram does it on the profile page to switch between grid view and single scroll view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I couldn't figure it out (it probably has something to do with the tableView content underneath it), I decided to go with a workaround using a touch gesture:

```
@IBOutlet weak var tabBar: UITabBar!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    let tabBarTap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(MyViewController.switchSelectedTabItem(tapGestureRecognizer:)))
    tabBarTap.delegate = self
    tabBarTap.numberOfTapsRequired = 1
    tabBarTap.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1
    tabBar.addGestureRecognizer(tabBarTap)
}

@objc func switchSelectedTabItem(tapGestureRecognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    let touchPoint = tapGestureRecognizer.location(in: self.view)
    let split = tabBar.frame.width/2    //because i have two tab bar items. divide it by how many tab bar items you have
    if touchPoint.x > split {           //again, since i have two tab bar items, i can just divide the location of the tap into two sections (tab bar item 1 and tab bar item 2)
        tabBar.selectedItem = tabBar.items?[1]
        //run code for when second item is selected
    } else {
        tabBar.selectedItem = tabBar.items?[0]
        //run code for when second item is selected
    }
}
```